# PL/SQL and entity framework, create a dynamic inserting procedure and call from EF

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, stored-procedures, plsql

What I need to do is:
Create a procedure that once defined a temp table, fills it with data, then from entity framework I will operate a select * from that table and work with the data.

This is what I've got so far:

code for create table and fill

```
    create  global temporary  table tempzzo
  (ID_UTENTE NUMBER NOT NULL, FIELD1 VARCHAR2(50), FIELD2 VARCHAR(5), FIELD3 VARCHAR2(30))

Create or replace procedure SCHEMA.TEST_P
is 
   stmt varchar2(1000);
begin
    stmt := 'insert into tempzzo SELECT 123 ,S.FIELD1, S.FIELD2, S.FIELD3 from GEMINI.TABLEEXAMPLE S where rownum < 10;';
    execute immediate stmt;
    COMMIT;
end;
```

but if I do "select * from tempzzo;" i find the table empty. What is it???
I've tried to put a commit in the procedure but nothing changes.

I would be glad if someone can show me how to call it from entity framework too, with the dbcontext.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` to the end of the statement creating the GTT. Then the rows will not be deleted on commit; instead they'll be deleted when the session ends.

Comment: How to preserve them after the stored procedure execution?

I need to get those fields from Entity Framework (.NET) and the stored procedure will be the first part of the execution. I Want to commit them permanently and delete it manually later.

I Cannot define a new table as the fields will be dynamic and can change.

Comment: I don't know about entity framework, just pl/sql. I know that a global temporary table (gtt) has to have it's rows deleted either on commit or on session termination. Is it possible to do everything you want to do in the gtt in a single session? Have you considered using a regular table, defined using dynamic sql, and dropping it when your done with it?